# How to set timeout in shell script inside for loop?

Tags: shell

I am learning shell scripting where I have created `shell(.sh) file` to perform certain task. What I want to do is, iterate through an array and for each object of that array perform certain operation. If that operation takes more than a min then move to next object and so on.

FYI, this is my first .sh file.

**Issues:**

1. I am just able to get result of first value, it is not moving to next object. Also, in terminal, it looks like it is just running in background. I have to force stop it (ctrl + c).
2. Is timeout the only option (based on my research this is what I found)?

**Code:**

```
#!/bin/sh
LOGFILE="MyLog.txt"

ENDPOINT=SOME_VALUE

PREFIX=Output

declare -a numbers=(1061 1071 1107 1158 1271 1273 1275 1276 1278 1279 1282 1288 1305 1406 1447 1455 1472 1488 1490 1491 1492 1572 1718)

for number in "${numbers[@]}" 
do 
    echo "GetLogs: $number" >> $LOGFILE
    SOME_OPERATION >> $LOGFILE # If this takes more than 1m then move on to next
    timeout 1m >> $LOGFILE # Is this correct approach?
done
```

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/068 for some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix. The script was fine, it was just output to the log file was creating an issue. The reason is, SOME_OPERATION was downloading `.zip` file which created an issue when it tries to make an entry in log.

**Following Works!!!**

```
#!/bin/sh
LOGFILE="MyLog.txt"

ENDPOINT=SOME_VALUE

PREFIX=Output

declare -a numbers=(1061 1071 1107 1158 1271 1273 1275 1276 1278 1279 1282 1288 1305 1406 1447 1455 1472 1488 1490 1491 1492 1572 1718)

for number in "${numbers[@]}" 
do 
    echo "GetLogs: $number" >> $LOGFILE
    SOME_OPERATION 
done
```